# Можно ли в Sass использовать & на прародителя?

Tags: css, sass, scss

```
.wrapper {
  width: 10px;
  &_item {
    &:hover {
      width: 20px;
      .wrapper_button { ????
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Можно ли вмеcто `.wrapper_button` использовать амперсанд?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-2

Comment: Так а что на выходе вы хотите получить?

Comment: Это sass или все же less синтаксис в примере?)))

Comment: @Air это синтаксис scss с компилятором sass, насколько я понимаю. Объявление хотя бы одной переменной сказало бы точно.

Comment: scss, я же написал

Comment: на выходе получить то же, что и в коде, только чтоб не нужно было писать второй раз wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По простому - нет. Вы не можете с помощью амперсанда выбрать уровень. Но вы можете использовать переменные:

```
.wrapper {
  $ws: &; // wrapper selector
  width: 10px;

  &_item {
    &:hover {
      width: 20px;

      #{$ws}_button {
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, результат тогда такой

```
.wrapper {
  width: 10px;
}
.wrapper_item:hover {
  width: 20px;
}
.wrapper_item:hover {
  color: black;
}
```